# Problem installing

Tags: system-installation

So first time I try to install Eos it always fails to grub, then I wipe the disk and install it again (doing that first time went okay) but I could not chose windows from grub, that left me with changing the system with one time quick boot, so I deleted and found out that windows is installed in legacy mode and there's a way to fix it via Linux, so I went on, tried to install Eos, first time it failed to install grub (obvious) and second time after wiping the disk again it said setup was successful, yet this time it doesn't even show up grub at the beginning of boot, it goes straight into elementary os. This is getting really irritating.

---

### UPDATE

Okay I reinstalled windows, wiped all other disks, installed elementary and it started working.

Comment: It is very good experience. Great to share. I have this problem too and figured out with your second pose. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay I reinstalled windows, wiped all other disks, installed elementary and it started working.